# How to use WAF with a MacPorts installation

Tags: macports, waf

I have a project with uses WAF (not a project I originated). Some people are going to compile the project on Windows, others on Linux, some on OS X. Those compiling on OS X might use MacPorts, others use Homebrew, others might use custom compiled libraries installed in `/usr/local`.

I'd rather not hard-code paths such as `/opt/local` into `wscript`. What's the best practice for supporting all these different package managers on OS X? I'm just starting to learn about WAF, BTW. Is there a `--prefix` or some other option that allows WAF to look in `/opt/local` for headers and libs? Should all users who are compiling the project be required to set environment variables such as:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib"
export LDFLAGS='-L/opt/local/lib'
export CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/local/include'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
export LD_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include
```